# Does the power set of a set contain a copy of the elements in the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

If A is a set and P(A) its power set, then P(A) contains all the elements in A. P(A) also contains the subsets of A, which A doesn't necessarily contain.

So, does P(A) contain a *copy* of all the elements in A, and not the *same* elements?

Hence, if A = {x} is a singleton, B = {x} ⊆ P(A), then A and B are not the same element, despite A = B. Can this be clarified to me?

Comment: What is a "part of a set"?

Comment: Let "parts of a set" be "power set". Sorry, bad translation, fixing now.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I was clarified that if A = { {a} }, then a∉A. My books don't make this exclusion explicit.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm assuming here that "$P(A)$" means "the powerset of $A$."*

Your claim that in general $A\subseteq P(A)$ is **false**. For simplicity, let's work in naive set theory (although everything I say is also true in, say, ZFC). Then:

- The powerset of the set $A=\{$apple$\}$ is $P(A)=\{\emptyset, \{$apple$\}\}$.
- However, apple isn't an element of $P(A)$: $\emptyset\not=$ apple and $\{$apple$\}\not=$ apple.

I think the key point is this last bit: **in general, we won't have $x=\{x\}$.** (Indeed, in ZFC we *never* will have this, by the axiom of regularity!) The ur-example is $\{\emptyset\}$ versus $\emptyset$ (one of these isn't empty!).

---

What *is* true is that there is a natural injection of $A$ into $P(A)$: for $a\in A$, the set $\{a\}$ is an element of $P(A)$, and the map $A\rightarrow P(A):a\mapsto \{a\}$ (the "singleton map") is injective. That is, for each element $a$ of $A$, the powerset $P(A)$ contains something *corresponding to* the object $a$, namely $\{a\}$. But this is not *the same thing as* the object $a$.

Comment: Thank you. Since P(A) is disjoint from A, is the element a∈A the same element a∈{a}∈P(A)? I don't understand if both elements referred to as`a`, contained in two disjoint sets, can be the *same* element, of if they are copies of each other. Up until now my books left ambiguity on this concept.

Comment: @davide Note that I **didn't** say that $P(A)$ is always disjoint from $A$; e.g. if we take $A=\{\emptyset\}$, then $P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\emptyset$ is an element of both $A$ and $P(A)$. However, let's for simplicity look at the case $A=\{a\}$, where $a\not=\emptyset$ and $a\not=\{a\}$ (these stipulations ensure that $A$ and $P(A)$ are disjoint; the second is guaranteed if we assume the axiom of regularity, but some set theories don't have that). The objects $a$ and $\{a\}$ are distinct, and we have $a\in \{a\}$ and $\{a\}\in P(A)$ but $a\not\in P(A)$. (cont'd)

Comment: I'm not sure what "copies of" means. We have $A=\{a\}$ and $P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}$; every $a$ is the same as every other $a$, but $a$ and $\{a\}$ are different things. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you again. I was probably influenced by the fact that in computer science every element belongs to a memory location, and if two distinct locations contain the same element, then they are equal copies of each other.